# Why use multiple features in Linear Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

Linear regression defines Y is a function of X. Using this function can predict Y using values of X before they occur (ignoring outliers).

Uni-variate linear regression depends on just one variable. But a more powerful form is multi variate linear regression, where instead of using just one parameter : X , use multiple parameters. This can not be visualized on X,Y plane, introducing 3 parameters can perhaps be visualized, but 4,5,6 parameters (dimensions) can not.

The idea being that with more parameters will give a better prediction. What is the basis of this ? Why does using multiple features improves the quality of the prediction ? Intuitively I understand the more that is known about a problem then a more accurate prediction can be made. But why does adding more features, or in other words dimensions increase the function accuracy ? Does a formal definition exist of this ?

Or is it just trial and error - one feature may be enough but will not know for sure until test with multiple features.

Comment: The case of multiple features is just a generalization of the case with just one feature, where your weight vector has zeros for all but one feature. So it's not possible to get a worse fit, simply because you are free to ignore additional information.

Comment: "The idea being that with more parameters will give a better prediction." Not necessarily. If you use too many parameters, the resulting model can be overfitted. Anyway, you should ask this question on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This is really a more appropriate discussion for the stack cross validated. Overflow should be used for coding questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formal proof is very simple. **The nature of your mapping f cannot be expressed as a function of your features**. You can only get some approximation, and adding more variables **always** expand the space of possible approximators (to be more strict - **never reduces**). While it might be actually **harder** to find a good approximator in this new space (and so all known algorithms will fail), there will be always a greater chance that it **exists**. Generally - if you can create a perfect set of features, for example .... output values themselves - then adding anything will actualy reduce quality of the model. But in real life - we as humans - are not capable of finding such good predictors and so we sample blindely what can be obtained, measured from reality, and as a simple random guessing - each additional piece of information might be usefull.

If you prefer more mathematical solution, consider `f` being a function of unknown set of features

```
f(x1, ..., xm) e R
```

now you can measure features in some infinite space of raw signals `r1, r2, ...`, and for each subset of raw signals there is a mapping onto these true features of `f`, but with various degree of correctness, so you have `g1(r1, r2, r3) = (x1+er1, 0, x3+er3, ...); g2(r1) = (0, 0, x3+er4, ...)` etc. You are trying to build function from some finite subset of raw signals into `R` which will approximate `f`, so the greater amount of `r` you include, you have better chance of capturing such elements, which will make approximating `f` possible. Unfortunately - you can add many redundant signals, or those, which are completely uncorrelated with true features. This might be seen as a great problem of bias-variance. The more features you add, assuming that you do this in the whole spectrum of possible signals (and so you can actually find something truly related to the nature of `f`), the more variance you will introduce. And on the other hand - small set of features introduce high bias error (due to strong assumptions about required signals, and their correlactions with true features).

In particular, linear regression is not well suited for working with highly correlated signals, so for this particular statistical model, adding new signals can quickly lead to destroying your model. There is a strong, underlying assumption of LR that `f` is a linear model of all your predictors up to **normally distributed errors, with equal variances among each dimension**.

Comment: "adding more variables always expand the space of possible approximators"  in other words :  a learning function with more parameters will have higher degree of variance in its computed value as more parameters gives a greater range of function operands ?

Comment: well it is more complex than just "range of function operands"; it relates more to the fact, that you simply expand the space of possible functions. If all parameters lie in the same manifold, then adding more of them does not expand the space, while you still get "greater range of function operands", the point is that you can actually span more of the "true" domain through introduction of (at least partially) orthogonal signals

Comment: Can I ask for a reason of "-1" vote? If the answer is incorrect/missleading please provide your doubts so it can be improved

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on what @lejlot said, I would say that increasing number of features will not always increase the probability of modelling the correct regression model as there are chances of overfitting of training model. Rather finding features which are independent of each other and still contribute to overall model.

I would suggest this particular post to understand more about linear regression and how more features help :

http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf

Comment: How does it add anything to the answer? Overfitting is clearly stated "The more features you add, assuming that you do this in the whole spectrum of possible signals (and so you can actually find something truly related to the nature of f), the more variance you will introduce" high variance error = overfitting in machine learning/statistics.

Comment: The link would be a good way to make somebody understand linear regression.